# How to use Block inheritance in EJS templates

Tags: express, ejs

base.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Diary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script src="javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

});




</script>

</body>
```

index.ejs:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<h1>Welcome to Your Diary</h1>
<div>


<span class="label label-default">What would you like to do? </span>&nbsp;
<span class="label label-primary">Here are your Categories:</span>&nbsp;


</div>
</div>
```

I want block inheritance

Comment: No blocks in EJS but here is a simulation of blocks https://github.com/dheeraj-br/ejs_layout_implementation

Answer (score 7):

> EJS does not specifically support blocks, but layouts can be implemented by including headers and footers, like so:
>
> ```
> <%- include('header') -%>
> <h1>
>   Title
> </h1>
> <p>
>   My page
> </p>
> <%- include('footer') -%>
> ```

https://github.com/mde/ejs#layouts

You could split base.ejs into two files, header and footer, like this:

**header.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Diary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script src="javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
```

**footer.ejs**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Despite is a dirty solution this does indeed work and is the correct answer (without adding additional code nor packages)

Comment: yes but inhertance is more easier to slot things.

Answer (score 7):

Someone has made EJS with block inheritance capability (https://github.com/mafintosh/pejs)

Straight from the documentation (Retrieved on January, 1st, 2018):

> Using blocks it's easy to implement template inheritance. Just declare
>   a `base.html` with some anchored blocks:
>
> ```
> <body>
>   Hello i am base
>   <%{{ content }}%>
> </body>
> ```
>
> Then a `child.html` that renders `base.html`
>
> ```
> <%{ './base.html' }%>
> <%{ content %>
>   i am inserted in base
> <%} %>
> ```
>
> To render the example just render `child.html`
>
> ```
> pejs.render('./child.html', function(err, result) {
>   console.log(result);
> });
> ```

Looks pretty good. I'm going to try this on my own project.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ejs-locals` or `ejs-mate` engine for ejs

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late. I am in the same situation. What you can do is to pass the content you want to render in the properties of the object. Like this:

```
<%- include('/partials/',{
      title: 'my title',
      tags: [
        '<h1>Hi, my name is this</h1>'
      ]
    });
 %>
```

EJS does not support blocks, but this is the solution I have implementate. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts (> 11k downloads this week)

It's support block inheritance, extract css + css in view and put it into a specific place.

You can check the example code in the NPMJS link above.

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around could be to add a `div` with an `include(aBlock)` in the middle of you `base.ejs`:

```html
<!-- your-header -->
...
<div class="main-container">
    <%- include(aBlock) %>
</div>
...
<!-- your-footer -->
```

and pass the variable from the server. For example in Express:

```js
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('base', {aBlock: './home'})
})
// or 
app.get('/about',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('base', {aBlock: './about'})
})
```

given that `home.ejs` and `about.ejs` are in the same folder as `base.ejs`, otherwise fix the path accordingly